# Mean squared estimation

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

Given $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ when given $\sigma^2=1$. We are interested in an estimation of mean squared $g(\mu)=\mu^2$. We consider the following estimator: $\hat{g}=\overline{X}^2$. Find $E_{\mu}\overline{X}^2-\mu^2=$.

My guess was that it will be $\mu-\mu^2$ but in my textbook the answer states that $1/n+\mu^2-\mu^2$. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the definition of variance:

$$ Var[\bar{X}] = E[\bar{X}^2] - E[\bar{X}]^2$$

This means

$$ E[\bar{X}^2] = Var[\bar{X}] + E[\bar{X}]^2$$

So you just need the two values on the right side of that equation. Expectation is linear, so:

$$E[\bar{X}] = E[X] = \mu$$

And assuming your variables are independent:

$$ Var[\bar{X}] = \frac{Var[X]}{n}  = \frac{1}{n}$$

This gives you the answer you want